# Detect changes to NSManagedObject when saving

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

KVO makes it possible to observe individual properties of an object and get notified of both old and new value. However, is there a way know when saving a `NSManagedObject` what specific attributes have changed and what were their values at the last save/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NSFetchedResultsController to do just that. As long as you set a delegate to your NSFetchedResultsController, you'll have calls to -didChangeObject, which provides what you're looking for.

Comment: Hmm, [`NSFetchResultsController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) doesn't seem to have a method called `-didChangeObject`, also it is not available on Mac, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: It's NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate that has the method. Here's the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate